# Exporting json from Angular Library

Tags: angular

I created a library that I wish to contain a collection of default json configuration objects that the user can use in consuming application. I put these json objects in json files, set resolveJsonModue: true in my tsconfig to allow importing json files, import them into a barrel index.ts, and try to export them in my public-api.ts.

I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export * as areacharts from './area-charts';
```

I'm pretty sure this is because I'm just json files here. Is there a way I export elements from my .json files from my library, or should I move them to .ts files?